# Laravel array_only with dot notation

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel has a helper that allows you to get only the keys you want like so:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-only

```
$array = ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100, 'orders' => 10];

$slice = array_only($array, ['name', 'price']);

// ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 100]
```

However, how can I get the `array_only` equivalent that also allows dot notation. e.g.

```
$array = [
    'name' => [
        'first' => 'John',
        'last' => 'Smith',
    ],
    'levels' => [
        'maths' => 6,
        'science' => 10,
    ],
    'age' => 25,
];

$slice = array_dot_only($array, ['name.first', 'levels']);

/*
[
    'name' => [
        'first' => 'John',
    ],
    'levels' => [
        'maths' => 6,
        'science' => 10,
    ],
];
*/
```

Comment: Can you be clearer about what you want to achieve ?

Comment: What more detail do you require? I've added an example of input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off @Edwin's answer:

```
function array_dot_only(array $array, $keys): array
{
    $newArray = [];
    $default = new stdClass;
    foreach ((array)$keys as $key) {
        $value = array_get($array, $key, $default);
        if ($value !== $default) {
            array_set($newArray, $key, $value);
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

This brings the function even closer to `array_only` because it will include items where the key is set but the value is null. It does so by using an object as the default and checking if the `$value` is that same object.

Answer (score 4):

Laravel makes this easy with pre-existing helpers array_set and array_get that do support dot notation.

```
function array_dot_only($array, $keys) {
    $newArray = [];
    foreach((array) $keys as $key) {
        array_set($newArray, $key, array_get($array, $key));
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slight modification to @Devon's answer:

```
function array_dot_only(array $array, $keys): array
{
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ((array)$keys as $key) {
        $value = array_get($array, $key);
        if (isset($value)) {
            array_set($newArray, $key, $value);
        }
    }
    return $newArray;
}
```

This change will make its behavior more aligned with `array_only()`'s, because `array_only()` will not insert fields that does not exist in the source `$array`.